# Does Amazon have any rules restricting political erotica?

Tags: self-publishing, amazon, erotica

I have outlined the plot of an erotic story featuring some WWII Nazi characters who are portrayed as being brutal, but arousing. I'm concerned about community standards at Amazon and other publishing platforms. Amazon's written standards are pretty vague. Does anyone have insight?

Specifically, this is a BDSM story with Nazi characters in dominant and submissive encounters. I'm worried that portraying Nazis as arousing that I might be viewed as endorsing Nazi beliefs. I do not.

I know there are porn stories on Amazon such as dinosaur erotica that's "code," but I can't find any such rule-bending for Nazis.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Is there any particular reason you want to portray Nazis as being "arousing"?

Comment: What is your concern? Too brutal? That you might be glorifying Nazis?

Comment: Yes, to both F1Krazy and Laurel. This is a BDSM story with Nazi characters in dominant and submissive encounters. I'm worried that portraying Nazis as arousing that I might be viewed as endorsing Nazi beliefs. I do not.

Comment: While I don't have any insight into what Amazon (or other sites) might allow, you could probably side step some or most of the issue by changing the setting (and character identities) to something fictional. You'd need to put more effort in, but then you'd know that your audience will feel what they're feeling because of your world building and not because you're leveraging society's trauma.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this "Political Erotica" which I thought was going to be a shipping fic between a Democrat senator and a Republican ("Senator, I would like you to take a look at... my bill.  You should know that I'm a hard-liner on the matter at hand.).  Or a fanfic shipping the Bill and the Boy from School House Rock.   Somehow, I didn't think Nazis were covered.

Comment: Given the quantity of similar novels listed on Amazon after a simple google search using the keywords of this question, its hard to imagine they have a policy that would restrict the  sale of your story solely based on the setting and subject matter.

Comment: There is a community of erotica writers on Reddit where you may get an answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/eroticauthors/